# Revit .Net API has function overloading, however Python doesn't support overloading

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell

I am using this function - [NewFamilyInstance Method (Line, FamilySymbol, View)](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/899076fd-73d2-5be0-8872-b8f389d4ba49.htm). However, this function has overloading in API.

[image]

The .net support function overloading, however Python doesn't support that. How can Revit Python API work in this case?

When I use one of these functions and pass the different parameters, how can this work properly?

```
fis = db.Collector(of_class='FamilyInstance')

start_point = XYZ(1, 0, 0)
end_point = XYZ(2, 0, 0)

line = Line.new(start_point, end_point)

views = db.Collector(of_class='View')
ItemFactoryBase.NewFamilyInstance(line, fis[1].Symbol, views[1])
```

The code above gave me the following error in `RevitPythonShell`

`ItemFactoryBase.NewFamilyInstance(line, fis[1].Symbol, views[1])`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: NewFamilyInstance() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

I just found it might be not caused by function overloading. Actually this function is not a static method but a common method.

[image: The]

However, when I tried to initilize it and get an instance of the class. It complained - `no public constructor`.

[image]

Comment: In general, you should not relay on Revit.Net API cause different languages has it's pwn drawbacks and API may change from one language to another

Comment: What is PWN? Is there a different way to use Revit Python API? It has to go though .net library, right? Because it is just how it works @ArturMustafin

Comment: Yes, the Revit API is .NET based and every access must go through .NET.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, please be aware that we are also discussing this same question in the Revit API discussion forum thread on [Revit .Net API has function overloading; however, Python doesn't support overloading](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/revit-net-api-has-function-overloading-however-python-doesn-t/m-p/11385669).